# Variable not found with data mask

Tags: r, tidyeval

```
library(rlang)
myquo <- quo((Temp - 32) / 1.8)
eval_tidy(myquo, data = as_data_mask(datasets::airquality)) # works
e <- as_env(datasets::airquality, parent = global_env())
eval_tidy(myquo, data = as_data_mask(list(), parent = e))   # error
```

I expected `Temp` to be found in `e`. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have R version 3.5.0 and tested this with both latest CRAN and GitHub version of {rlang}.

Comment: This is interesting because both `get("Temp", as_data_mask(list(), parent = e))` and `get("Temp", as_data_mask(list(Temp=1), parent = e))` work as expected. It probably makes more sense to post this to the rlang issues page though: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues

Comment: I'm new at using {rlang} so I've no idea if the issue comes from me or from {rlang}.

Comment: Interesting that `R> e
<environment: 0x000002042ebbcb48>` & `as_data_mask(list(), parent = e)
<environment: 0x000002042eabd958>` returned different results

Comment: @Tung is that interesting though? That's basically like `new.env(parent=globalenv())`, right? You would expect that to return something different. There needs to be a new object to hold the parent information.

Comment: @Tung I think this is normal because `e` is the parent, not the environment itself. See `env_parents(as_data_mask(list(), parent = e))`.

Comment: #TIL. Thanks guys.

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/571) on {rlang}'s repo.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation might have been updated since the question was asked, but for new visitors, the relevant part of the rlang documentation for as_data_mask is:

> **parent**  Soft-deprecated. This argument no longer has any effect. The parent of the data mask is determined from either:
>
> - The env argument of eval_tidy()
> - Quosure environments when applicable

So in the case of `eval_tidy(myquo, data = as_data_mask(list(), parent = e))` the `env` of eval_tidy and the quosure env on `myquo` are both the global env, and the data mask itself is empty, hence why `Temp` is not found.

```
eval_tidy(myquo, data = as_data_mask(datasets::airquality))
```

works but has an unnecessary call in it, since the data argumnet of eval_tidy will convert a data.frame to a data mask anyway, so the easiest way would be.

```
eval_tidy(myquo, data = datasets::airquality)
```

On the other hand, if you really want to specify the environment explicitly in `eval_tidy`, you could use `expr` instead of `quo`

```
myexpr <- expr((Temp - 32) / 1.8)
eval_tidy(myexpr, data = as_data_mask(list(), parent = e)) # still fails since parent is overridden 
eval_tidy(myexpr, data = list(), env = e) # works since there's no quosure env to override env
```